# VBA: using multiple For loops, or one big?

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I've been recently wondering about which is better in terms of efficiency: to use multiple For loops, or one big loop containing many operations?

I work with 50k-100k rows in 17 columns from SQL database.

Now, a sample of code:

```
z = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To z
    If Cells(i, 15) <> 0 Then Cells(i, 19) = 1 Else Cells(i, 19) = 0
Next i

For i = 2 To z
    Cells(i, 20) = Val(Left(Cells(i, 2), 2))
Next i

For i = 2 To z
Select Case Cells(i, 18).Value
    Case Is = 1
        Cells(i, 29).Value = 1
    Case Is = 2
        Cells(i, 29).Value = 1.6
    Case Is = 3
        Cells(i, 29).Value = 2.8
End Select
Next i

For i = 2 To z
    Cells(i, 30) = Val(Right(Cells(i, 14), 1))
Next i

For i = 2 To z
    Cells(i, 31) = ((Cells(i, 18) + 1) * Cells(i, 16) * Cells(i, 17)) / 1000000
    Cells(i, 31).NumberFormat = "0.00"
Next i
```

My question is: is it wiser to do those operations by columns (separate For loop for every column), or by rows (one big loop containing all operations for each record)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viewed in its entirety the performance bottleneck will be in the acquisition of the data records, not in how the loops are structured.

You're best aiming for readability rather than attempting to over-optimise code that will be a negligible contributor to execution time.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will agree that readability is in fact an important matter, I only wondered if the performance improvement would be significant enough to sacrifice the former. From what I understood, the answer is "no", so I'll keep my code as it is :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be very slow because you are making a large number of calls to the object model to retrieve values from individual cells. There is a large overhead associated with each call.

It would be much faster to read all the required values into a variant array:

```
dim vArr as variant
vArr=Range("A1").resize(z,31).value2
```

and then process the resulting 2D array before returning the processed array to the worksheet

Answer (score 0):

If you are validating the records in excel with those in Database then you can apply big for loop; but I can even suggest to use find() method if you have loops inside loops.
(Find() Method can improve the performance)

Comment: Not at all, the initial data remains untouched and I use the output of those loops for later generation of pivot tables. I'll keep that in mind though if I ever find myself in need of validation :)

Answer (score 0):

I second *Bathsheba* as to what the bottleneck operation is gonna be.
However, whenever you have a long macro inserting lots of data, you might want to put this chunk of code **Before** your first loop:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

And this one **at the end** of your operations:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

It will first disable screen updates, events and formula recalculation, and re-enable it once it finished its operations.

Depending on the kind of operations you are doing, I found this to optimize the speed of a macro up to 75%.

Comment: I have this at the very beginning of the macro: `Application.ScreenUpdating=False`
`Application.DisplayAlerts=False`(for automatically deleting temporary worksheets). I don't use in-sheet formulas, I guess that's what `Application.Calculation` is responsible for?